# Открыть декстоп приложение в open-server

Tags: openserver, electron

Всем привет, разрабатываю декстоп-приложение на electron для диплома. Кто-нибудь знает, как сделать так, чтобы open-server  открывал не старицу в браузере, а окно приложения?

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/ru/docs/latest/tutorial/launch-app-from-url-in-another-app

Comment: @nörbörnën, не нашел ответа на свой вопрос

Comment: Страницу в браузере открывает пользователь. Open-server выдаёт открываемые страницы по запросу пользователя. Конечно сервер может выполнить что угодно, получив запрос, в том числе и запустить программу. Но только на том же компьютере, где работает сам. Если это то, что Вам нужно, то какие проблемы? Поместите вызов функции запуска внешней программы в свой php-скрипт (exec, например)